# Why does a non required field in a serializer serialize the field?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Say I have a serialiser like

```
class DumbSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field_one = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
```

And I do something like

```
asdf = DumbSerializer(data={})
asdf.is_valid()
>>> True
asdf.data
>>> {'field_one': None}
asdf.validated_data
>>> OrderedDict()
```

Why is the serialization of `{}` represented as `{'field_one': None}` and not `{}`, given that `field_one` is not a required field?

The docs state "Setting this to False also allows the object attribute or dictionary key to be omitted from output when serializing the instance. If the key is not present it will simply not be included in the output representation."

The python internal representation is an empty dict as I would expect

Answer (score 0):

*Please mention your exact requirement.*

All fields mentioned in the serializer will be available in the JSON output, if you want any other default value other than None, you can add a default parameter in the field

```
field_one = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, default='1')
```